# Using c# web api with alternate content-type

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, content-type

I'm new to web api and I need to create a server for a client. I have no control over the client - can't change a thing.

The client sends in an html encapsulated json request in a POST body. However, the content-type can vary. What do I need to do to allow my ApiController to process different content-types?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Under the hood, Web Api supports *Content Negotiation* mechanism to automatically opt the correct formatter based on the header `Content-Type` in HTTP request.

By default content negotiation supports three formatters: `json`, `xml` and `form-urlencoded data`. If no formatter found, client will receives HTTP error 406 (Not Acceptable).

See more:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/content-negotiation

If you need to allow Web Api support another `Content-Type`, you can write your own custom formatter:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/media-formatters

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using this:
  public HttpResponseMessage Post(HttpRequestMessage  r)
{

}

This allowed me to get access to the raw xml coming in which I could then parse. I'm sure it's not the "right" way - but it works for me